# Code pipeline passing S3 bucket as User Parameters to lambda function in AWS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-codepipeline, aws-serverless

I'm creating a serverless lambda and want to invoke it as a code pipeline in the final stage after the deployment stage is successful.

in the user parameters i'm passing the S3 bucket name,  [image]

How i can access the user parameters in the lambada to get bucket name and version ID.

Below is my lambda which it should make put to dynamoDB table which each deploy and increment version number.

```
'use strict';
const uuid = require('uuid');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

Here's Fiddle for my lambda [Put lambda](https://jsfiddle.net/91w0x7zm/)

I'm missing the how to access user parameters in requestBody in my lambda and increment the version, can you shade some light on

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: How to post to update the deploy version and post it to the dynamoDB on each deploy?

Answer (score 1):

It says on the console that the user parameter will be on the `event` object that is passed to your Lambda function. I don't know exactly where it will be. The easiest way to find out is by calling `console.log(JSON.stringify(event))` and looking at the event to see where your user parameter is.

To increment the version number, you can increment counters in DynamoDB by using an UpdateExpression. There is a an example here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_Examples

Answer (score 0):

You can access the User Parameters like this:

```
data = event['CodePipeline.job']['data']
param = data['actionConfiguration']['configuration']['UserParameters']
```